# Checking if One String Equals Another Changing String at a Certain Point in Time with Javascript

Tags: javascript

There is a string that is always changing it's text.  I made a variable for this string by using querySelector:

```
var lastBall = document.querySelector('span#banner')
```

What this string is is it's a countdown for a roulette wheel that spins every 30 seconds.  What I am currently trying to do is log a number (1234) into console anytime that the countdown is at 25.06 seconds remaining until the wheel spins.

I have tried using a while statement to log the number while lastBall is equal to "Rolling in 25.06" (This is the text that's displayed when there's 25.06 seconds remaining before the wheel spins)

```
while (lastBall.innerText == "Rolling in 25.06") {
console.log("1234")
```

}

This only returned "undefined" in the console.  I'm assuming that a while statement won't work for what I'm trying to do.  Apparently a setInterval would work somehow, but I'm not sure exactly what code I need to paste into console in order to get this to work.

So in summary, I'm trying to log "1234" into console if the text of lastBall is equal to "Rolling in 25.06".  Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You should edit the code that sets the text.

Comment: "I'm not sure exactly what code I need to paste into console" Are you a sheep or a programmer? Experiment! Google!

Comment: @Feathercrown I probably wouldn't have asked my question here if I hadn't googled nor experimented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setInterval(function(){
  if(lastBall.innerText === "Rolling in 25.06") console.log("1234");
}, 10);
```

A `while`loop blocks the execution while a really fast running Interval doesnt.

Comment: However, this will waste lots of CPU.

Comment: Agreed, it's far better to just set an interval for the time it will happen. That's a problem with the question, though, not your answer.

Comment: @SLaks i bet the OP does not own the site and its rather in the addon way. However i totally agree...

Comment: @JonasW. Thanks a ton!  This is the exact code I needed for it to work.  And to address the concerns about CPU waste, this was just a test.  The actual string that I need to compare will stay on the screen longer, so I've set the interval higher.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Marty youre welcome ;) while performance is no matter then, hooking into the method that updates the page is probably more elegant ;)